# Fix "unmanaged" network interface if it worked before

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, ipsec

**TL;DR;**
Maybe I clicked vpn connect wrong and got disconnected from the network. That's why the answer is easy.

As usual I wanted to connect to my work network using ipsec via network manager applet. Previously it worked ok but this time after I press "connect" -  networking stopped working completely. All my network interfaces are "unmanaged". I tried restarting my laptop - didn't help.

I see only solution to reinstall my NixOs (and not even sure if this will help).

I tried:

- Manually "managed yes" my wlp59s0 interface.
- Restarting services: NetworkManager, wpa-supplicant, strongswan.
- Add unmanaged=no to the 10-globally-managed-devices.conf

I checked journalctl and didn't see anything strange.

System info:

- Linux 6.6.6
- Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174.
- Os: NixOs unstable.

nmcli device:

`wlp59s0 wifi unmanaged --`

ip a:

```
wlp59s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
...
```

I tried up it - didn't help.

I'll repeat one more time that wifi and tunnel worked fine for several days (before I used openvpn, also Ok), then one click - nothing works. Only `ping localhost` works :( How this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason networking was disabled. So `nmcli networking on` fixed this issue. Maybe it's my oversight, but I think I've seen this flag unchecked before, so I assumed it was OK if it was off (I thought wifi flag would be enough in the nm applet)